# Is there an easy way to bulk unsubscribe from following users on Reddit?

Tags: reddit

I'm following hundreds of users (possibly a thousand) and would like to make a backup list of them and unfollow all of them, so I'm only subbed to actual subreddits.

Does anyone know of any way I might be able to do this?